# How would I determine or calculate the metal work function of an alloy

Tags: semiconductor-physics

I am trying to build a schotky diode but based on a little bit of physics that I might use for kids at a high school. Specifically to build a point contact/cats whisker diode.

From the theory I have so far, to make a metal contact diode a crystal must make contact with two different metals, one of which becomes a schotky diode contact and the other an Ohmic contact.

The rule of thumb I have is as follows. If

the "Metals Work function" > Semiconductors "Electron Afinity" => DIODE  , and

the "Metals Work function" < Semiconductors "Electron Afinity" => OHMIC CONTACT

But the trouble I have is that many of the metals I should/can use are alloys,
for instance the early diodes used a Phosphor Bronze point contact,
which is about (92% copper, 7.7% tin, 0.3% phosphorus), I can find out each 
individual metals workfunction, but don't know if I can just amortize each metals workfunction for the alloy. I have seen one paper which seems to indicate that the workfunction is lowered by metal alkali alloys by more than either metal, but I may not have read that graph/paper correctly.

For more information on metal workfunctions see Wikipedia
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_function

Well any advice or assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Sincerely
Michael

Comment: An ohmic contact was assumed to be produced at different places on a large area of contact with clamps and screws. The difficult thing was to find a rectifying junction on a sweet spot with the point contact. This would depend on local variations of surface oxides etcetera. The phosphor bronze is for springiness.